# The sign of the energy released by an explosion

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, energy-conservation, conventions, explosions

On a simple system with no external force, we can calculate the energy released by an explosion as the difference of the sum of the kinetic energy before and after.

With kinetic energy $K_i$ (initial) and $K_f$ (final), when some form of energy is released, $K_f < K_i$. Thus to calculate the released energy, (I think) one should $K_i - K_f$. However, the textbook is suggesting the opposite as shown in the image below.

[image]

Moreover, $K_f > K_i$, so wouldn't that mean energy was absorbed instead of being released?

Comment: Did you really mean to say  the kinetic energy is less after the explosion?

Comment: @BobD Shouldn't it be less if any form of energy (heat, light, sound, etc.) was released during the explosion? Apart from that, doesn't the English phrase "energy was released" mean that there was loss in kinetic energy? But I'm actually quite confused now.

Comment: In the explosion chemical  potential energy is converted to kinetic energy, heat, light , sound etc.  these are all added to any original kinetic energy the device happened to be in motion (e.g. a hand grenade)

Comment: It is very easy to see that $KE_f > KE_i$ because you can start with something that has $KE_i=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the physics principle you can use here is just conservation of energy.

```
KE1 + V1 = KE2 + V2
```

What you really want to know is how much of the potential energy was converted into kinetic energy. If the system had some non-zero kinetic energy before the explosion, then you want to discount that. Because you want to know how much of the internal energy of the system was converted to kinetic energy. So

```
KE2 - KE1 = V1 - V2
```

So `delta K` gives you the difference between the initial and final potential energy of the system. That difference is the energy that was "released" as a result of the explosion reaction.

If the system was initally at rest then you simply get

```
KE2 = V1 - V2
```

which just says that some of the potential energy got released in the form of kinetic energy. If it helps think of it as not an explosion but something like two blocks connected by a spring and the spring is compressed initially by means of a thread binding the blocks together. Then you cut the string. In that picture you can see that the potential energy of the spring is released as kinetic energy of the blocks and the amount of energy released is the total kinetic energy of the blocks afterwards.